# what induces a person to become more devoted in his religious pursuits?

Tags: mussar-ethics

Looking for some sources as to what induces a person to become more devoted in his service of God.

I have read about certain big tzadikim who devoted themselves with extreme mesirut nefesh (efforts) and was wondering from where does this desire come from.

For example, the Rambam in Mishne Torah yesodei tora [ch.2](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904962/jewish/Chapter-Two.htm) says this desire comes from examining the wisdom in nature.

> What is the path [to attain] love and fear of Him? When a person
>   contemplates His wondrous and great deeds and creations and
>   appreciates His infinite wisdom that surpasses all comparison, he will
>   immediately love, praise, and glorify [Him], yearning with tremendous
>   desire to know [God's] great name, as David stated: "My soul thirsts
>   for the Lord, for the living God"

are there other sources that discuss what induces a person to this strong devotion? and why should that approach be the most powerful one.

Comment: Are you looking for anecdotes? Biographical sketches? Personal testimonies? Analyses of Mussar principles? Analyses of psychological principles? Please make this more specific and clear.

Comment: Why has modern science dulled this more than ancient science?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman well modern science posits it all just happened by chance through random evolution - not by God, and they try to bring evidences to support their claim.

Comment: @ray Check out Epicuriu'ss or Lucretius's writing some time.  Then read Einstein's philosophy on G-d.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman thanks but for what? aren't they not torah based sources?

Comment: looking more for torah based source

Comment: Rambam is saying that one should meditate on the greatness of G-d, and that this will cause one to feel great love for and yearning for Him, motivating you to serve Him enthusiastically. (This is actually similar to Chabad spirituality, if I understand it correctly.) Even if you think science explains the universe, there are still many reasons to be in awe of the greatness of G-d.

Comment: So, is the premise of this question that you're unsatisfied with the Rambam's approach, so you're looking for alternatives? Is this question really based on the assumption that "modern science has dulled a bit the impact of this study"? If so, that seems to be an invitation for people to post answers that challenge that assumption. Also, if you're looking specifically for sources that address contemporary sensibilities, that's an important aspect of the question that should be made more explicit. If the Rambam's strategy is out-of-date, so probably are those of other Rishonim and Chazal.

Comment: @IsaacMoses really just looking for alternative answers to the rambam's approach. i updated the queston

Comment: @Kordovero science cannot explain the universe. it can take you perhaps near the big bang but of course, scientists cannot understand what was before that.

Comment: @ray That is like saying "science cannot explain what is in my hand" (there is nothing in my hand). There is no "before the big bag".

Comment: @mevaqesh just saying big bang itself is beyond the realm of science. no way to observe for one.

Answer (score 1):

This comes from an in depth study of the Chovos Halevavos, especially the first 3 gates. There's a translation online.

Here is a quote from the Shaar Bechina (Gate of Examination)

> The wise and intelligent man will choose from the world for study its
>   fine and spiritual elements; use them as a ladder by which to obtain
>   proofs of the existence of the Creator of all, **to Whose service he
>   will then cling to according to** his heartfelt recognition of the
>   greatness and exaltedness of the Creator, and his realization of the
>   Almighty's gracious benevolence to all of His creations and that G-d
>   has graciously bestowed abundant benefits to him, and has elevated him
>   (above the animals, etc.) while he had done nothing nor possessed any
>   moral quality that would entitle him to deserve any divine reward.

Answer (score 0):

Where does desire for greater devotion come from? One answer is that it can result from direct attempts to cultivate that desire and yearning. See these two links, with various relevant quotes from Rebbe Nachman of Breslov:

http://azamra.org/Essential/desire.htm

http://www.azamra.org/Advice/will.html

How to stimulate this desire or yearning, beyond these suggestions? Through praying aloud in our own words, asking Hashem to give us a passionate desire to serve Him with all our might. See the following links:

http://azamra.org/Essential/hisbodedus.htm

http://www.azamra.org/Advice/meditation.html

http://www.azamra.org/Advice/prayer.html

You'll also find a lot of answers to this question in Mesilas Yesharim by Ramchal, which can be read for free online here.

http://www.shechem.org/torah/mesyesh/